# MySQL JOIN: How to

Tags: mysql

I have a big select statement that find out what a contact's current left device and right device is.  It works fine.  The big select also returns the contact_id of the person.

Here it is...

```
 SELECT locations.name AS location_name, CONCAT_WS(' ', contacts.first_name, contacts.last_name) AS contact_name, contacts.street_1, contacts.street_2, contacts.city, contacts.state, contacts.zip, contacts.home_phone, contacts.cell_phone, contacts.email, sel.side, delivery_date AS delivered_date, CONCAT_WS(': ', makes.name, models.name) AS details, sel.serial_number, contacts.warranty_expiration_email, contacts.warranty_expiration_letter, contacts.upgrade_letter, contacts.email_newsletter, contacts.mail_newsletter
 FROM

 (SELECT 'Left Device' AS side, left_sn AS serial_number, contact_id, left_make_id AS make_id, left_model_id AS model_id, MAX(left_delivery_date) AS delivery_date
 FROM
 invoice_hearing_aids
 WHERE left_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND left_return_date IS NULL AND trial_complete = 'Y' AND left_price IS NOT NULL AND company_id = '1' AND left_delivery_date = (SELECT MAX(t2.left_delivery_date)FROM invoice_hearing_aids t2 WHERE t2.contact_id = invoice_hearing_aids.contact_id)
 GROUP BY contact_id

 UNION

 SELECT 'Right Device' AS side, right_sn AS serial_number, contact_id, right_make_id AS make_id, right_model_id AS model_id, MAX(right_delivery_date) AS delivery_date
 FROM
 invoice_hearing_aids
 WHERE right_delivery_date IS NOT NULL AND right_return_date IS NULL AND trial_complete = 'Y' AND right_price IS NOT NULL AND company_id = '1' AND right_delivery_date = (SELECT MAX(t2.right_delivery_date)FROM invoice_hearing_aids t2 WHERE t2.contact_id = invoice_hearing_aids.contact_id)
 GROUP BY contact_id
 ) sel

 LEFT JOIN hearing_aid_models models ON models.id = sel.model_id
 LEFT JOIN hearing_aid_makes makes ON makes.id = sel.make_id
 LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = sel.contact_id
 LEFT JOIN locations ON locations.id = contacts.location_id
```

I want to add a row of info.  I want to return a column that has the contact's LAST APPOINTMENT date.

The appointments table has start_date and a column called post_appt_status_id.  I want to return the MAX(start_date) WHERE post_appt_status_id IN (6,7).

If there is no appointment in the appointments table, just return NULL.

I tried adding this to the end:

```
 LEFT JOIN appointments appt ON appt.contact_id = sel.contact_id
 WHERE appt.post_appt_status_id IN (6,7)
```

and I addded this to the beginning SELECT at the top:

```
 MAX(appt.start_date)
```

But it isn't returning all the records.  In fact, I'm only getting 1 row and I should be getting 1972 rows which is what I got before I added my appts JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you added an aggregate function (MAX), but didn't specify the grouping. Ordinarily, that should just throw an error.

Try adding a `GROUP BY sel.contact_id` to the very end and see what that nets you.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that. I'm only getting 920 records.

Comment: Isn't the point to reduce it down to only the most recent appointment? I assume many of those contact_id rows are for multiple appointments, right?